# Display Message inside div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to display this message within the div. If I repeat this code,
it appears in the same place every time, I just want to display it in
its own div and not invade others.
My big problem it's the display message.
Does anyone know how to resolve this?

I'm using html, css and javascript

```html
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      jhadfjadfjasf
      ajdfhkhasdjfas
      ajdfhjadfa
      ajdfhkajsdfh
      <div class="sidney">
         <img src="https://eitrawmaterials.eu/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/person-icon.png" width="220px" height="220px">
         <div id="baselayer">
            <input type="button" class="testx" value="SubLevel" onclick="showFrontLayer();" /> 
            <input type="button" value="Job Description" onclick="showFrontLayers();"/>
            <div id="bg_mask">
               <div id="frontlayer">
                  <div class="containers">
                     <input type="button"  value="X" onclick="hideFrontLayer();" style="position: absolute;top:5%;right:5%;"/>
                     O Product Owner é a pessoa que define os itens que compõem o Product Backlog e os prioriza nas Sprint Planning Meetings.
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div id="bg_masks">
               <div id="frontlayers">
                  <input type="button" value="X" onclick="hideFrontLayers();" style="position: absolute;top:5%;right:5%;"/>
                  O Product Owner.
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <style>
         .sidney{
         width: 250px;
         height: 250px;
         background-color: black;
         border:20px;
         }
      </style>
      <img src="https://eitrawmaterials.eu/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/person-icon.png" width="170px" height="150px">
      <style>
         #testx{
         position: absolute;
         top: 0px;
         left: 0px%;
         transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
         -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
         background-color: #555;
         color: white;
         font-size: 16px;
         padding: 12px 24px;
         border: none;
         cursor: pointer;
         border-radius: 5px;
         text-align: center;}
         #bg_mask{
         position: absolute;
         top: 0px;
         right: 0;  
         bottom: 0;
         left: 0;
         margin: auto;
         margin-top: 0px;
         width: 981px;
         height: 610px;
         background : url("img_dot_white.jpg") center;
         z-index: 0;
         visibility: hidden;
         } 
         #frontlayer{
         position: absolute;
         top: 0px;
         right: 0;
         bottom: 0;
         left: 0;
         margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
         padding : 30px;
         width: 180px;
         height: 100px;
         background-color: orange;
         visibility: hidden;
         border: 1px solid black;
         z-index: 1;
         } 
         #bg_masks {
         position: absolute;
         top: 0;
         right: 0;  
         bottom: 0;
         left: 0;
         margin: auto;
         margin-top: 0px;
         width: 981px;
         height: 610px;
         background : url("img_dot_white.jpg") center;
         z-index: 0;
         visibility: hidden;
         } 
         #frontlayers {
         position: absolute;
         top: 0;
         right: 0;
         bottom: 0;
         left: 0;
         margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
         padding : 30px;
         width: 180px;
         height: 100px;
         background-color: orange;
         visibility: hidden;
         border: 1px solid black;
         z-index: 1;
         } 
      </style>
      <script>
         function showFrontLayer() {
           document.getElementById('bg_mask').style.visibility='visible';
           document.getElementById('frontlayer').style.visibility='visible';
         }
         function hideFrontLayer() {
           document.getElementById('bg_mask').style.visibility='hidden';
           document.getElementById('frontlayer').style.visibility='hidden';
         
         }
         
      </script>
      <script>
         function showFrontLayers() {
           document.getElementById('bg_masks').style.visibility='visible';
           document.getElementById('frontlayers').style.visibility='visible';
         }
         function hideFrontLayers() {
           document.getElementById('bg_masks').style.visibility='hidden';
           document.getElementById('frontlayers').style.visibility='hidden';
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

My big problem it's the display message.
Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: you have duplicated ids: `bg_masks` and `bg_masks`

Comment: aside from duplicate ids, your parent needs to be positioned anything other than static - ergo make sidney relative